# How to launch Applet in IE 8 so that it always works - tag Object vs Applet?

Tags: java, applet

What is the best way to launch Java Applet in IE8 ?

The problem is that in some IE browsers (IE8+XP+Java 1.6.0_35) the OBJECT tag below does not launch the applet;

```
> <object classid="clsid:8AD9C840-044E-11D1-B3E9-00805F499D93" codebase=
> ..
```

But the APPLET tag works in test page http://javatester.org/version.html

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best way to launch Java Applet in IE8 ?

`deployJava.js` - as mentioned in the [applet tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/applet/info).  It was developed by Sun and is now maintained by Oracle.  It is designed to embed the applet using whatever element the browser requires.